# Entity Framework Core 7 index attribute usage for multiple unique columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, multiple-columns, unique-index

I have an entity which requires both `Email` and `Title` to be unique. What's the diff between `[Index(nameof(Email), IsUnique = true), Index(nameof(Title), IsUnique = true)]` and `[Index(nameof(Email), nameof(Title), IsUnique = true)]`?

Comment: They aren't the same. First create three independent indexes. It's just shorthand for three independent `Index` attributes. The second creates a single multi-column index

Answer (score 0):

The second one (the `[Index(nameof(Email), nameof(Title), IsUnique = true)]` one) will generate the [composite index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#composite-index) which will check uniqueness  across multiple columns, i.e.  `Email` + `Title` pair will be checked for uniqueness, not the individual columns while the first one (`[Index(nameof(Email), IsUnique = true), Index(nameof(Title), IsUnique = true)]`)  will create 2 indexes both unique for corresponding single columns.